# How to keep my reducer pure when using Redux Promise Middleware?

Tags: redux, redux-promise-middleware

I'm using [Redux Promise Middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware) and my action creator returns an action with a promise.

Now, in the reducer, I receive the resolved promise data and I have to 'provide' the new state. I also have to do something that is not 'pure' with that data, e.g., store it in local storage.

How should I approach this situation and still keep the reducer pure? That data is obtained in middleware and the first time I get it is in reducer.

I know I can handle the promise in my action creator and access the data before dispatching the action but is there another better way?

Comment: `redux-observable` / `redux-saga` are middlewares to take care of this.

Comment: No, Redux Observable and/or Redux Saga won't take care of this. The question is about how to store data in local storage while keeping pure the reducer(s) that use said data.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own [`middleware`](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#the-final-approach)!

You can call it `localStorage-middleware` for instance and you can dispatch the action before providing your data to the reducer. Your middleware will listen to that action, like `dispatch(saveDataToLocalStorage(dataToSave))`

Comment: I'll try this approach. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend this approach as well! Just make sure the middleware follows Redux Promise Middleware in your middleware chain—this ensures the fulfilled action is always dispatched first.